# Multiple Spring's Transaction Manager over single method

Tags: spring, transactional

I have two Spring's Transaction Manager -

1. HibernateTransaction Manager.
2. MyCustomTransaction Manager written by me.

At this point over every method @transactional is bound to HibernateTransaction Manager. I want both Transaction Managers to run on that method.

Something like -

```
@transactional
@transactional(value="mycustomManager")
method(){
  /* transactional method*/
}
```

But I am not able to figure out how to acheive this as multiple annotations are not supported. One way i could see is splitting the methods-

```
@transactional
dummyMethod(){
method();
 /*dummy method*/
}

@transactional(value="mycustomManager")
method(){
  /*transactional method*/
}
```

But this approach is not scalable changing at all places. Any leads would be greatly appreciated ?

Comment: Why it should make sence to have two Transaction Managers for one query?

Comment: Why do you need a custom transaction manager? Looks like you are solving a problem in the wrong place.

Comment: I was thinking about implenting an interface.